# Excel macro downloading files

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am currently making a macro that when i click on the button on the excel spreadsheet, it will go to this website and download the file onto my desktop and save it with the file name "flower.jpg". how would i go about doing this? the website i am downloading this file from is my own website using php coding and such, but i am kinda new to vba macro programming. please help.

i currently have this code but it always gives me an error which i have no clue what for.

```
my.computer.network.downloadfile(website link here, my desktop location)
```

Thank you

Comment: Same code as VB6; http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/urldownloadtofile.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a password protected site, try this code instead

my.computer.network.downloadfile(website link here, my desktop location, username, password)